# Automatically Setting JAVA_HOME to latest JDK version

Tags: java, java-home

I need to set the JAVA_HOME to the latest JDK version which is present in the 64_bit folder.
Currently, I am setting this to :
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/hotspot/8/64_bit/jdk1.8.0_172

So is there any way it is automatically picked up the latest JDK version because every time I need to change the script when a new version comes.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, there is not an automatic way to do this.

Comment: If you know that all jdks will be installed in `/opt/java/hotspot/8/64_bit/` then you can probably find the latest version with a couple of lines of shell script. Alternatively, create a symlink that always points to the latest version.

Comment: On a Mac, this can be done by `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`, and that directory is updated by the installer.

Comment: Thanks @afrischke... Working fine.   cd /opt/java/hotspot/8/64_bit
var1="$(ls -t1 |  head -n 1)"
echo "${var1}"
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/hotspot/8/64_bit/"${var1}"
echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/java/hotspot/8/64_bit/jdk1.8.0_172

Comment: @FullStackDeveloper Hopefully this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in a couple of lines of shell script. There are probably a myriad ways to implement this. The following code relies on `sort`'s `-V` flag to find the latest version.

```
#!/bin/sh
BASE_DIR=/opt/java/hotspot/8/64_bit/

version=$(ls $BASE_DIR | grep -Eo "([0-9]+\.?){3}(_[0-9]+)?" | sort -Vr | head -1)

if [ -n "$version" ]; then
  folder=$(find $BASE_DIR -maxdepth 1 -name "*${version}*")
  echo "Setting JAVA_HOME to $folder."
  JAVA_HOME="$folder"
  export JAVA_HOME
else
  echo 1>&2 "No JDK installation found in ${BASE_DIR}!"
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

**Automatically set JAVA_HOME for openjdk**

Set java version:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
update-java-alternatives --list
update-java-alternatives --set /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Automatically set JAVA_HOME

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(update-alternatives --display java | grep -e "link currently points to" | sed 's/\  link currently points to //' | sed 's/\/bin\/java/\/jre/g')
```